# What's wrong with my implementation of an interpolation search algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

So I've got an implementation of an interpolation search algorithm in Java here:

```
public static boolean search(int key, int[] array) {
    int low = 0, high = array.length - 1;
    int middle = -1;

    while(low <= high) {
        middle = low + (((high - low) / (array[high] - array[low])) * (key - array[low]));
        if(array[middle] == key)
            return true;
        else {
            if(array[middle] < key)
                low = middle + 1;
            else
                high = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works for values within the array's range, always returning true, but for values outside my array's range it doesn't work (i.e. if i have a list of elements from 1-15, the values 0 and 16 won't work as I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

I can't seem to figure out from the debugger where i'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `key` variable is used for calculating the `middle`, thus it has to be validated before the loop to be checked if it's lower than the lowest value and higher than the higher value in the array:

`while((array[high] != array[low] && key >= array[low] && key <= array[high]))`

If the statement is false, then there's **no need** to go inside the loop because you know a priori that the key is not inside the array (since the array is sorted).

Check the implementation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) as well.